# GraphQL query issue - shopify polaris

Tags: reactjs, graphql, shopify-app, polaris

I got an issue with graphQL when I was developing the shopify app.
The logic is simple. I need to get *lineItems* from the shopify store using the graphQL.
Here is the code for gql.

```
const GET_ORDER_DETAIL = gql`
query getOrderDetail($orderId: String) {
  order(id: $orderId) {
    name
    physicalLocation {
      id
    }
    lineItems (first:100){
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

And here is my React code.

```
{
  this.state.refund_list.map((list, index) => {
    const orderId = `gid://shopify/Order/${list.order_id}`; // I got correct orderId.

    return (
      <Query key={index} query={GET_ORDER_DETAIL} variables={{ id: orderId }}>
        {({ data, loading, error }) => {
          if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>;
          if (error) return <div>{error}</div>;
          console.log(data);
          return <div>test</div>;
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  })
}
```

And here is Error sentence.

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: GraphQL error: Type mismatch on variable $orderId and argument id (String! / ID!)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `id` instead of `ids` in the `Query`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I edited that. but have a same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct type for `$orderId`.
I changed the `String` to `ID!`

Here is my fixed code.

```
const GET_ORDER_DETAIL = gql`
query getOrderDetail($orderId: ID!) {
 ...
}
`;
```

```
...
<Query key={index} query={GET_ORDER_DETAIL} variables={{ orderId }}>
...
```